# how does kubernetes effect CPU cache (e.g. L3) locality of a program

Tags: docker, kubernetes, scheduler, cpu-cache

when I run pods in kubernetes do I lose cache efficiency since it is constantly evicting the pod from the pipeline in a fair time scheduler (therefore constantly evicting and moving in cache tables)? Does the CPU retain some cache locality throughout the process?

e.g. Can containers retain some cache locality or for security reasons is this impossible (all containers are calling the same .so in separate containers but these containers have the same base image where the .so exists-- could that stay in cache across the scheduler)?

Comment: If you're running it in Kubernetes, you likely have multiple physical nodes, and if a pod gets evicted it's likely to get reloaded on a different node.  If you're sufficiently performance-sensitive to think about individual clock cycles and cache misses, it might not be the right environment for you.

Comment: I was talking about cache eviction not pod sorry that wasnt clear. Thats too bad it should be able to reuse .so's etc. Maybe we need something that is like to containers what containers are to VMs? like shared hierarchy layered docker builds (The more I type the more I realize Im kinda talking about unix services but not really)